# Mix server and app originated Facebook App Events

Tags: android, ios, server, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have integrated Facebook SDK App Events in a mobile app (Android and iOS), which automatically sends the launches and installations events, plus some custom events to Facebook. So far so good.

Now, I have been asked whether I can send some extra events but not via the app. Instead, the request is that our backend system sends these events to Facebook. These are business events that are more complex to manage within the app. However, these events must somehow glue with those send by the app for the same user.

Is this possible? Is there a way to get a Facebook SDK "id" for each user and use this is in a server-to-server call to send users events directly from our backend to Facebook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems possible via the /activities API. The underlying `advertiser-id` and `anon-id` can be easily extracted on client side.